Generic container wrapper type with a default underlying buffer
I've come up with a type that allows me to encapsulate any container class (that supports std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>) with a buffer and a memory resource object. So it has three member variables. However, one downside of it is that it's by default neither copyable nor movable. So it should better be constructed at the use-site (and not earlier only to be passed around).
I also declared an explicit default constructor to prevent initialization with user-specified arguments since that could lead to errors. The existence of the explicit default constructor causes the trait std::is_aggregate_v to return false which I think is the correct design choice for this struct.
And I chose buffer_resource_container as the name of this generic struct template. I could not find a better name.
Then there is also a utility function template reserve_capacity that takes any std::vector type and calls its reserve function and does not throw in the case of failure.
Here is a minimal example:
#include <concepts>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <system_error>
#include <new>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>


template <class Container, std::size_t DefaultBufferCapacity>
requires ( std::same_as<typename Container::allocator_type, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<typename Container::value_type>> )
struct [[ nodiscard ]] buffer_resource_container
{
    alignas ( alignof( typename Container::value_type ) ) std::array<std::byte, DefaultBufferCapacity * sizeof( typename Container::value_type )> buffer;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource buffer_resource { std::data( buffer ), std::size( buffer ) };
    Container container { &buffer_resource };

    buffer_resource_container( ) noexcept ( noexcept( Container { &buffer_resource } ) ) = default;
};

template <class ValueType, std::size_t DefaultBufferCapacity>
using buffer_resource_vector = buffer_resource_container<std::pmr::vector<ValueType>, DefaultBufferCapacity>;


template <class ValueType, class Allocator>
[[ nodiscard ]] std::errc inline
reserve_capacity( std::vector<ValueType, Allocator>& vec, const std::size_t new_capacity ) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        vec.reserve( new_capacity );
    }
    catch ( const std::bad_alloc& )
    {
        return std::errc::not_enough_memory;
    }
    catch ( const std::length_error& )
    {
        return std::errc::value_too_large;
    }
    catch ( const std::exception& )
    {
        return std::errc::resource_unavailable_try_again;
    }

    return std::errc { };
}

int main( )
{
    constexpr auto default_capacity { 500uz };
    static buffer_resource_vector<char, default_capacity> brv { };
    auto& buffer { brv.container };
    const auto cap { 200uz };
    const auto err_code { reserve_capacity( buffer, cap ) };

    if ( err_code != std::errc { } )
    {
        std::cout << "An error occurred during buffer allocation:"
                  << std::make_error_condition( err_code ).message( )
                  << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}

As can be seen, the requires clause of the struct enforces a constraint. What other constraints can be employed? Maybe one that makes sure the container has a constructor that takes a const Allocator& argument (since it is needed in the struct).
The code in main shows how I think buffer_resource_container and reserve_capacity can be used together to improve efficiency by lowering the chances of doing reallocations.

What can be improved here? Are there any issues in the code above? Any suggestions?

For reference: live

The container wrapper is pretty nice. There are quite a few cases where the ideal container is something like a static_vector or inplace_vector. But instead of hardcoding the container type, you made this generic. There are some issues though:
It's not as convenient as a regular container
Ideally, you'd be able to write something like:
static buffer_resource_vector<int, 10> bvr{};
bvr.push_back(42);

However, you require that one writes brv.container.push_back(42). You can get the convenience of the above code if you make buffer_resource_container inherit from Container:
template <class Container, std::size_t DefaultBufferCapacity>
requires (std::same_as<typename Container::allocator_type, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<typename Container::value_type>>)
struct [[nodiscard]] buffer_resource_container: public Container
{
    alignas(typename Container::value_type) std::array<std::byte, DefaultBufferCapacity * sizeof(typename Container::value_type)> buffer;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource buffer_resource {std::data(buffer), std::size(buffer)};

    buffer_resource_container() noexcept(…): Container{&buffer_resource} {}
};

You might want to add a get_container() convenience function to allow easy access to just the container part:
Container& get_container() {
    return *static_cast<Container*>(this);
}

You could also make it easier to write the desired type, consider:
template<template<class, class> class Container, class T, std::size_t N>
class Inplace: public Container<T, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>> {
    using container_type = Container<T, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>>;
    using value_type = container_type::value_type;
    alignas(value_type) std::array<std::byte, N * sizeof(value_type)> buffer;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource buffer_resource{std::data(buffer), std::size(buffer)};

public:
    Inplace() noexcept(…): container_type{&buffer_resource} {}
};

This allows you to write:
Inplace<std::vector, int, 10> bvr;
bvr.push_back(42);

About reserve_capacity()
I don't think this function is very useful. It's only working for std::vectors, but ideally you want something that works on any kind of container, and maybe for more than just reserve(). You can make a generic wrapper function or class that can take any function and when calling it, catches those exceptions and converts them into a std::errc, although it's a bit of work and maybe less pretty.

[…] reserve_capacity can be used […] to improve efficiency by lowering the chances of doing reallocations.

But with a std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource you typically use it with a large enough buffer to begin with, so you won't have reallocations at all, so reserve() would be useless. It could still give a very small performance benefit as adding elements to the container within the reserved size would not have to call into the allocator, but I'm not sure it is worth it. I would only do this is benchmarking and profiling the code tells you that this is really problematic.
If you reserve more than the initial buffer size, then what is the point of using a std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource to begin with? At least when combining this with a std::vector, as both the monotonic buffer resource and the vector will grow their allocations geometrically.

Standard advice is not to subclass standard library containers - could you elaborate on why it's not harmful in this case?

"But with a std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource you won't have reallocations at all, and the memory is already there" No, actually the user can request more capacity than what is already available in the buffer member. The container will switch to dynamic allocation in this case. This means the call to reserve can throw. Hence I put it in the function reserve_capacity that catches the exceptions.

@TobySpeight It's a good point. Nothing is virtual so we don't have to worry about the STL container's destructors not being virtual. Another issue is slicing, which is not a problem when accessing the container. Maybe there is a scenario where copying the sliced container is problematic?

@digito_evo Oops, you are right. I was assuming you'd use a std::pmr::null_memory_resource as the upstream allocator.

"what is the point of using a std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource?" Well, the size of the initial buffer should be chosen wisely and probably also generously. Exactly how I'm planning to use this type in a few places in my code. For example there are cases where I can easily calculate/predict the size of the initial buffer to prevent its exhaustion at runtime. However there is still the possibility that in the future runs of the program, the amount data will increase and eventually the initial buffer won't be sufficient. So the presence of a fallback to dynamic allocation must be guaranteed.

Also in the use cases that I'm designing this class for, the reserve_capacity function will be called only once. So either the initial buffer will suffice and no dynamic allocation will occur or it won't suffice and reserve will do a single dynamic allocation and forget about the initial buffer. And this is because the actual amount of data that is going to be stored in the container cannot be determined at compile time but I am fortunately able to make a pretty precise precalculation. In short, reserve won't be called more than once.

I see. This sounds like a very specific case. It might help to add more review context in that case. Maybe there is an even better solution possible?

"You might want to add a get_container() convenience function to allow easy access to just the container part" I think I like this approach better since it avoids inheritance and overly complicated code. Take a look at this please: here. I used the new deducing this feature (and disallowed the rvalue overloads).

@G.Sliepen You might want to have a look on this. I made it safer and clearer to use but making it a class with all the data members being private.

Nice. Consider creating a new Code Review question with the updated code.

I posted a follow-up question: here
